# Linecache getline does not work after my application was installed

Tags: getline, linecache

I am creating a tool that gives an overview of hundredths of test results. This tool access a log file, checks for Pass and Fail verdicts. When it is a fail, I need to go back to previous lines of the log to capture the cause of failure. 
The linecache.getline works in my workspace (Python Run via eclipse).  But after I created a windows installer (.exe file) and installed the application in my computer, the linecache.getline returns nothing.  Is there something I need to add into my setup.py file to fix this or is it my code issue?

Tool Code

precon:
from wx.FileDialog, access the log file

```
    self.result_path = dlg.GetPath() 
    try:
         with open(self.result_path, 'r') as file:
         self.checkLog(self.result_path, file)

def checkLog(self, path, f):

        line_no = 1
        index = 0
        for line in f:
             n = re.search("FAIL", line, re.IGNORECASE) or re.search("PASS", line, re.IGNORECASE)
             if n:
               currentline = re.sub('\s+', ' ', line.rstrip())
               finalresult = currentline


                self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(index, finaltestname)
                self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 1, finalresult)

                 if currentline == "FAIL":

                    fail_line1 = linecache.getline(path, int(line_no - 3)) #Get reason of failure
                    fail_line2 = linecache.getline(path, int(line_no - 2)) #Get reason of failure                    
                    cause = fail_line1.strip() + " " + fail_line2.strip()
                    self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 2, cause)

                    index += 1
             line_no += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by doing the get_line function from this link:
[Python: linecache not working as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127418/python-linecache-not-working-as-expected?rq=1)